# Mysql Connection has not been null after committing transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Mysql TRANSACTION connection has not been null after committing TRANSACTION with MYSQL ADO.NET.

Because there is no use of MYSQL TRANSACTION after committing so it should be null.

As It works fine in SQL TRANSACTION with SQL ADO.NET.

So can you help me with making Mysql connection null after committing it.

Below are the two transactions

MYSQL TRANSACTION

[image: MYSQL TRANSACTION]

SQL TRANSACTION

[image: SQL TRANSACTION]

Comment: I'm not a .NET person, but it seems to me you should be rolling back in the event that either a SQL exception occurred, or the result of the proc indicates that it did not succeed.

Comment: But once the transaction is committed then it can't be rollback.
My concern is to make Mysql connection null after committing or rollback.

Comment: No, I'm saying why would the transaction necessarily be `null` after a successful query?